# Can't get installRelease gradle task to show up in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have assembleRelease, which works, as well as assembleDebug and installDebug.

This is the chunk from my build.gradle, which I thought would get the task to show up, but the list still does not have it. Toggling the build variant does not have any effect on the gradle tasks that are appearing.

Any ideas?

Thank-you!

edit 1 - My top level build.gradle file ("Project : trunk") contains

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
dependencies {
}
```

My app-level build.bradle file is

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    dependencies {
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+"
        compile "ch.acra:acra:4.5.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('redact')
            keyAlias 'asdf'
            storePassword System.getenv("ANDROIDKEYPW")
            keyPassword System.getenv("ANDROIDKEYPW")

        }
        debug {
            keyAlias 'asdf'
            storeFile file('redact')
            storePassword System.getenv("ANDROIDKEYPW")
            keyPassword System.getenv("ANDROIDKEYPW")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true

        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

task incrementVersionCode << {
    println(":incrementVersionCode - Incrementing Version Code...")
    def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def patternVersionCode = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcherVersionCode = patternVersionCode.matcher(manifestText)
    matcherVersionCode.find()
    def mVersionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionCode.group(1))
    def mNextVersionCode = mVersionCode + 1
    def manifestContent = matcherVersionCode.replaceAll("versionCode=\"" + mNextVersionCode + "\"")
    println(":incrementVersionCode - current versionCode=" + mVersionCode);
    println(":incrementVersionCode - next versionCode=" + mNextVersionCode);
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}
task incrementVersionName << {
    println(":incrementVersionName - Incrementing Version Name...")
    def manifestFile = file("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    def patternVersionNumber = Pattern.compile("versionName=\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcherVersionNumber = patternVersionNumber.matcher(manifestText)
    matcherVersionNumber.find()
    def majorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(1))
    def minorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(2))
    def pointVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(3))
    def mVersionName = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + pointVersion
    def mNextVersionName = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + (pointVersion + 1)
    def manifestContent = matcherVersionNumber.replaceAll("versionName=\"" + mNextVersionName + "\"")
    println(":incrementVersionName - current versionName=" + mVersionName);
    println(":incrementVersionName - new versionName=" + mNextVersionName);
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}
task release << {
    println(":release - Build and Version Increment")
}
task debug << {
    println(":debug - Build")
}
incrementVersionName.mustRunAfter build
incrementVersionCode.mustRunAfter build
assembleRelease {}.dependsOn incrementVersionCode
assembleRelease {}.dependsOn incrementVersionName

dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` to your `release` build type:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    // other good stuff here
}
```

Your `release` closure inside of `signingConfigs` creates a named signing configuration. However, `release` as a name does not cause it to automatically get used by the `release` build type. You could have named the signing configuration `gregRocks`, then used `signingConfig signingConfigs.gregRocks` in the `release` build type, and gotten the same results.

Comment: If I add that, I get : Error:(23, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'signingConfig()'

Comment: @Greg: `signingConfig` has been around for quite some time. What version of the Gradle for Android plugin are you using? This would be in the `buildscript` closure, usually in the `build.gradle` file in the top level of your project.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2, so I believe it's Gradle 2.2.1 - (The path for Gradle in settings is "D:\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1")

Comment: @Greg: I repeat: what you are looking for is in the `buildscript` closure, usually in the `build.gradle` file in the top level of your project.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my question to post the entire contents of my build.gradle files!

Comment: I made a new project in Android Studio and noticed that it now uses "        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'". I updated my file and now your suggestion works fully :) Thanks a million!